# How to fetch row at given index from QSqlQuery

Tags: qt, qsqlquery

I am learning QT and using QSqlQuery to fetch data from database.

I have read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html) documentation. I know using next() function we can iterate through rows of QSqlQuery and using value(int col) function we can get data from current row.

But i dont know how to fetch row at particular index without using next() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not use `QSqlQuery` so far myself but from the documentation the [`seek`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#seek) method seems suitable to me:

```
bool QSqlQuery::seek ( int index, bool relative = false )
```

"Retrieves the record at position index, if available, and positions the query on the retrieved record. [...]"

Comment: Yes i just found same solution myself.
Actually i did not given too much attention to seek method because it returned bool. But when i went through doc again i found that seek method not only returns bool but also shifts cursor position at given index.
Thanks anyway i will accept your answer.